# Issue when using sscanf

Tags: c, linux, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to make a script in C, that reads bandwidth information from the file `/proc/net/dev` and process it to produce Upload and Download traffic per second.

The file looks like this:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:    4845      60    0    0    0     0          0         0     4845      60    0    0    0     0       0          0
enp3s0: 197557966  217836    0    0    0     0          0       591 21516707  160167    0    0    0     0       0          0
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

I switch between two networks(the other one is not listed in the file currently) so I have the name of the network device as an argument.
Currently `enp3s0` is the device I'm grabbing the network info from.

Now the problem I come across is when I try to process the required line using `sscanf` .
For some reason sscanf is always producing gibberish output for all kinds of values I'm reading from it.

So I made a seperate test file in which I declared the line as a string directly and used almost the exact same logic, in which it works perfectly as expected.

**Main file:**

Note: Some lines were commented out during troubleshooting.
And some lines only exist for verbose output.
Also the byte conversion part is still left as I didn't go further since I encountered this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NETWORK_FILE "/proc/net/dev"

//==========================FUNC_DECL
unsigned long * receive(FILE *,char*);
char *searchstr(FILE *,char *);

//===========================TYPE-STRING
typedef char *String;

//===========================FUNCTIONS
// The function that looks for argv[1] in the NETWORK_FILE and returns the line as char *.
char *searchstr(FILE *ndev,char *netid){
           int found=0,lineno=1;
           char tmpf[600];
           //GETTING THE LINE MATCH
           while(fgets(tmpf,sizeof(tmpf),ndev) != NULL){
                 if(strstr(tmpf,netid) != NULL) {
                            printf("Device %s Found on Line %d",netid,lineno);
                            found++;
                            break;
                 }
                 lineno++;
           }
           if (found==0){ printf("ERROR!::NO_NET_DEVICE::No such device exists as %s\n",netid); }

           char *line = tmpf;
           if(line == NULL){ printf("ERROR!:SEARCHSTR_NULL_LINE_RET: Empty Line being sent for parsing"); exit(2);}
           return line;
}
//The function that sends Upload and Download bytes to the Main function in an array ptr form.. sort of
unsigned long * receive(FILE *dev,char *netname) {
           unsigned int dspeed=0,uspeed=0,dump;
           unsigned long rcv1,rcv2,trv1,trv2;
           char *n_line = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
           char *drop =(char *) malloc(15*sizeof(char));

           n_line = searchstr(dev,netname); 
           if(n_line == NULL){ printf("Error!: No Line received for parsing"); }
           printf("\n Line Input is: \n%s",n_line);
//--------THIS IS THE MAIN LINE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. THE LINE BELOW IT IS THE ONE I WROTE TO TROUBLESHOOT
           /*sscanf(n_line,"%s %lu  %u    %u    %u    %u     %u          %u       %u %lu  %u    %u    %u    %u     %u       %u          %u",drop,&rcv1,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&trv1,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump);*/
           sscanf(n_line,"%s%lu",drop,&rcv1);
           printf("\nDrop is read as: \t %s\nRx is %lu",drop,rcv1);
           if(rcv1 == 0){ printf("\nError!:NULL_VALUE-RX-1: Value received for parsing is 0."); }
           sleep(1);
           sscanf(n_line,"%s %lu  %u    %u    %u    %u     %u          %u       %u %lu  %u    %u    %u    %u     %u       %u          %u", drop,&rcv2,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&trv2,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump,&dump);
           if(rcv2 == 0){ printf("Error!:NULL_VALUE-RX-2: Value received for parsing is 0."); }
           dspeed = rcv2-rcv1;
           uspeed = trv2-trv1;
           unsigned long *speeds [2];
           speeds[0] = &dspeed;
           speeds[1] = &uspeed;
           return *speeds;
}


//==========================Main
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

        FILE *netdev;
        String networkid = malloc(10);
        networkid=argv[1];
        netdev = fopen(NETWORK_FILE,"r");
        if (netdev == NULL) { printf("Error Opening file!"); return (-1); }
        unsigned long *spd[2];
        *spd = receive(netdev,networkid);
        printf("\n D: %lu | U: %lu \n",*spd[0],*spd[1]);
        fclose(netdev);
}
```

**Test file**:

Note: The test file has slightly older values since its using an old copy paste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
   char *w1,*w2,*w3,*w4,*w5;
   w1 = (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char));
   w2 = (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char));
   w3 = (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char));
   w4 = (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char));
   w5 = (char*) malloc(15*sizeof(char));
   unsigned long n1,n2,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7;
   char *teststring,*devstring;
   devstring = (char *) malloc(150*sizeof(char));
   devstring = "enp3s0: 168010376  192508    0    0    0     0          0       547 19528703  142230    0    0    0     0       0          0";
   sscanf(devstring,"%s %lu",w5,&d1);
   printf("\n\nDev line parse is:\n %s RX: %lu\n",w5,d1);
}
```

**Output**

Main file

```
Device enp3s0 Found on Line 4
 Line Input is:
enp3s0: 197678794  218123    0    0    0     0          0       617 21694353  160864    0    0    0     0       0          0


Drop is read as:                   <= There is usually gibberish here. Its different everytime. And sometimes its not there at all
Rx is 94544931811891
 D: 94544931811891
```

Test file

```
Dev line parse is:
 enp3s0: RX: 168010376
```

I am pretty much a beginner in C(this is my first ever program where I have used pointers. Still cant wrap my head around those) so will definitely have done some things in the worst/dumb ways imaginable. Feel free to correct me.

**Edit:**

So according to @Mathieu 's answer I tried incorporating a return check for sscanf:

```
           int assign_count = sscanf(n_line,"%s %lu %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %lu %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u",drop,&rcv1,&trv1);
           if(assign_count == 3){
               printf("\nRx is %lu",rcv1); 
           }else { printf("\nERROR!::RECEIVE_ASSIGN_FAILURE:: Failed to assign %d values(Current: %d)",3,assign_count); }
```

**Output:**
This gives me two different outputs randomly.

```
Device enp3s0 Found on Line 4
 Line Input is:
enp3s0: 201330925  226694    0    0    0     0          0       790 23566091  172240    0    0    0     0       0          0

ERROR!::RECEIVE_ASSIGN_FAILURE:: Failed to assign 3 values(Current: -1)
 D: 93951710999123
```

```
Device enp3s0 Found on Line 4
 Line Input is:
enp3s0: 201339561  226756    0    0    0     0          0       798 23586994  172381    0    0    0     0       0          0

ERROR!::RECEIVE_ASSIGN_FAILURE:: Failed to assign 3 values(Current: 2)
Error!:NULL_VALUE-RX-1: Value received for parsing is 0.Error!:NULL_VALUE-RX-2: Value received for parsing is 0.
 D: 0
```

In one case `ret` or `assign_count` comes out as -1 and in the other as 2. Also in some executions I come across **Segmentation Fault** randomly as well.

Comment: You should check the value returned by `sscanf` it will tell you how much conversions have been made, so how fields you can read

Comment: If you need to ignore a conversion, use `%*d`, instead of storing in `dump`

Comment: wait am I not doing that? The lines in output `Drop is read as:` and `Rx is ` are what I am using to check values fed by sscanf. Or are you saying that sscanf has a way where it can actually show me how my input string is formatted by default?

Comment: `char *line =(char *) malloc(sizeof(tmpf)); line = tmpf;` makes no sense.  You allocate space and then discard your only reference to it.

Comment: After `line = tmpf`, line holds an address that is invalid after the function returns.  You need a `strcpy` (or similar) instead of an assignment.

Comment: @WilliamPursell okay. But how does it work? From my limited understanding, -- "You first allocate enough memory for the char * and then feed it with the value required" which probably isn't correct. How does it actually work? Aren't you actually supposed to reserve space first and then feed it the value? -- Also I am printing the `n_line` to check if `line` carries over correctly to the next function and it does print the correct line.

Comment: Yes, you must allocate space and then copy data into that space.  But `line = tmpf` does not copy data into the space that you just allocated.  It just points line at a different location.

Comment: I created the line variable becaues `tmpf` was not returning and throwing a warning   **Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'tmpf' returned[clang: -Wreturn-stack-address]** . Hence I made the line variable.

Comment: `n_line` not defined and contents unknown.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so upon further troubleshooting I found that `n_line` is broken. It prints correctly as a whole but there's something off about it when I try to parse it.

First I analysed the `tmpf` variable in the `searchstr` function by using `strtok` and `for` loop printing the split strings. -It prints correctly as expected

```
char *wd;
wd = strtok(tmpf," ");
while( wd != NULL){
   printf("::%s\n",wd);
   wd = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

But when I run the same in the `receive` function on `n_line` it is yielding broken output - Either the first string is printed or some numbers are randomly printed from the line.

**The Solution: ..sort of**

However the whole problem just goes away in a whim when I declare `tmpf` as **`static`**.

When declared as `static` , `sscanf` writes all variables correctly and the verbose output also comes out right.

```
Device enp3s0 Found on Line 4
tmpf is : enp3s0: 4054772    8380    0    0    0     0          0       131  1842262   11148    0    0    0     0       0          0

 Line Input is:
enp3s0: 4054772    8380    0    0    0     0          0       131  1842262   11148    0    0    0     0       0          0
        Rx is 4054772 | Tx is 1842262
```

I don't really know why is it working suddenly, but my guess would be `static` makes `tmpf` stay in memory across both functions hence I am able to process its output correctly when in the second function. Still feels like this is more of a **hack** than an actual solution.
Some other outputs get broken as well but that is probably not part of this problem.

Edit:

I also just found a source stating this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `sscanf` could be better:

- read the result of `sscanf` before using its result
- know that scanf will ignore extra space between fields to read, you can write only one in your `format` parameter
- ask `sscanf` to ignored certain fields with `%*..`

Hence, your code will become:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char *lines[] = {
        "    lo:    4845      60    0    0    0     0          0         0     4845      60    0    0    0     0       0          0",
        "enp3s0: 197557966  217836    0    0    0     0          0       591 21516707  160167    0    0    0     0       0          0",
        "  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0"
    };

    long unsigned int rcv2, trv2, i;
    char name[256];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int ret = sscanf(lines[i],"%s %lu %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %lu %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u", name,&rcv2,&trv2);
        if (3 == ret)
            printf("%s, %lu, %lu\n", name, rcv2, trv2);
        else
            printf("Error: %d conversion(s) instead of 3\n", ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so the %* was really great advice. I was indeed looking for something like that for some time. Now I tried incorporating the `int ret =` logic in my code and it seems that sscanf fails to allocate all 3 variables. It is changing its values on each execution from -1 to 2. I'll update my question to include this output as well.